# Como remover a querystring ReturnUrl?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Como remover a querystring ReturnURL da minha página de Login ?

Comment: Você está usando `FormsAuthentication`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, Estou usando asp.net identity

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu uso e estou com mesmo problema!
Ela me gera o seguinte url 
http://localhost:50553/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fius%2fCadastroLocalidade.aspx
Poderia responder a pergunta por favor!

Comment: Favoritei. Respondo com mais tempo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não recomendo fazer isso porque é uma perda de funcionalidade importante (no caso, redirecionar o usuário para a página de onde ele veio e que não estava autorizado), mas vou demonstrar como remover.

## 1. Retire o parâmetro do formulário de login

No arquivo `Views/Account/Login.cshtml`, a linha que gera o formulário deve estar mais ou menos assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Modifique para:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

## 2. Retire os parâmetros dos Controllers

```
    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        // ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                // return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: no exemplo você explica como remover, e existe alguma forma de alterar?

Comment: @Rod O que você gostaria de alterar?

Comment: o parametro que fica na url login?returnurl= mudar esse returnurl para qualquer outra coisa, eu tentei alterar os viewbag e os nome dos parametros, mas me pareceu inútil, a menos se fiz algo errado

Comment: Para alterar vc precisa modificar onde o @CiganoMorrisonMendez citou para remover e incluir no startup.auth.cs `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, LoginPath = new PathString(("/account/login")), ReturnUrlParameter = "url-de-retorno" });`